# Started learning SQL recently, how do I fix the near "(" error in SQL?

Tags: sql

I recently started with SQL. I am trying to create a table, but I keep getting the following error:

> Error: near "(": syntax error

This is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE clients
(
    clientID int(5), 
    firstName varchar(15), 
    surname varchar(15), 
    email varchar(50), 
    phoneNumber int(10)
);
```

I tried checking if any of the punctuation marks are out of place. watched Youtube videos but still have no clue

Comment: Please do not spam (R)DBMS tags; just tag the product you are *really* using. I've gone ahead and removed the spam; you'll need to [edit] your question to (re)tag appropriately.

Comment: not reproducible in SQLite and actual error message missing for MSSQL, see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/ny6tcvJr), where actual error is: "Column, parameter, or variable #1: Cannot specify a column width on data type int."

Comment: OT a phone number is a string (varchar), not an int. It *is* a value consisting of (mostly) digits, but not a numerical value

Answer (score 1):

The syntax error you are experiencing is likely due to the use of (5) and (10) after the int data type in your clientID and phoneNumber columns respectively. The correct syntax for int data type does not require a length parameter.

You could write:

```
CREATE TABLE clients(


ClientID int,
firstName varchar(15),
surname varchar(15),
email varchar(50),
phoneNumber int
);
```

Answer (score -1):

The SQL syntax error in the given query is that the data type specified for the phoneNumber column is incorrect. The 'int' data type should be followed by the maximum value that can be stored within the field, i.e., the width of the field. Here is the corrected SQL syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE clients
(
    clientID int(5), 
    firstName varchar(15), 
    surname varchar(15), 
    email varchar(50), 
    phoneNumber bigint(10)
);
```